# Pandas: Change output values from float to int from columns with NaN values

Tags: python, pandas

I have a simple function that binary encodes `t` and `f` strings found within my dataframe. **note: df has missing values**

```
def binary_encoding(df):
    return df.replace({"t":1, "f":0})
```

The output is in `float` form, but i desire `int` values.

I tried:

```
 def binary_encoding(df):
    encode = df.replace({"t":1, "f":0})
    return int(encode)
```

but i get an error `int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'DataFrame'`.

Comment: `encode.astype(int)`

Comment: This is not related to the replace method but to `int(encode)`, since you can't convert the DataFrame itself to int

Comment: @mcsoini thanks for your input. I have applied your idea however, iget the following error: 
ValueError: Cannot convert non-finite values (NA or inf) to integer

Comment: Is the dataframe you are going to convert from float to int containing only numeric values ?  If yes, there is chance we can do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### You can use the [integer with N/A support](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/integer_na.html) data type:

Suppose you have 4 columns as follows:

3 columns have `NaN` values and one column without.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Col1': ['f', 't', np.nan], 'Col2': [np.nan, 'f', 't'], 'Col3': ['f', np.nan, 't'], 'Col4': ['f', 't', 'f']})


  Col1 Col2 Col3 Col4
0    f  NaN    f    f
1    t    f  NaN    t
2  NaN    t    t    f
```

Now, after your binary encoding by your function:

```
def binary_encoding(df):
    return df.replace({"t":1, "f":0})

new_df = binary_encoding(df)

print(new_df)


   Col1  Col2  Col3  Col4
0   0.0   NaN   0.0     0
1   1.0   0.0   NaN     1
2   NaN   1.0   1.0     0
```

Data types of new_df:

```
new_df.dtypes

Col1    float64
Col2    float64
Col3    float64
Col4      int64
dtype: object
```

#### Data type conversion using the [integer with N/A support](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/integer_na.html) data type:

```
new_df_int = new_df.astype('Int64')


print(new_df_int)


   Col1  Col2  Col3  Col4
0     0  <NA>     0     0
1     1     0  <NA>     1
2  <NA>     1     1     0
```

**Data types of new_df_int:**

```
new_df_int.dtypes

Col1    Int64
Col2    Int64
Col3    Int64
Col4    Int64
dtype: object
```

**You now have the integer data type and display as integers as you want!**

You can also apply the data type conversion to individual columns instead of the whole dateframe, e.g.:

```
new_df['Col1'] = new_df['Col1'].astype('Int64')
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to return the dataframe with int values, try:

```
def binary_encoding(df):
    encode = df.replace({"t":1, "f":0})
    return encode.astype("int")
```

UPDATE:

If you have NaN values in your dataframe, decide how you want to handle them. You can either `df.dropna()` or `df.fillna()`. You can also handle infs similarly by first converting them to NaN `df.replace([np.inf, -np.inf], np.nan)`

Something like:

```
import numpy as np

def handle_na_and_inf(df):
    df = df.replace([np.inf, -np.inf], np.nan
    df = df.dropna()  # use fillna() if you want to fill with another value
    return df
```

Comment: Thanks Mike. The approach returns an error:
ValueError: Cannot convert non-finite values (NA or inf) to integer

Comment: I see, since you have NaN of inf values in your dataframe, you will need to decide how you want to handle them first. If you want to drop them, use `dropna()`, you can also fill them in with your choice of value using `fillna()`. Both are pandas dataframe operations

Comment: is there an alternative solution than dropping any further data? Since the original solution doesnt require dropping any rows/columns, I am just confused as to why its such an issue converting floats to Ints in dictionary outputs.

Comment: You don't have to drop, as mentioned, you can use `fillna()` to fill in the NaN with a value of your choice. It is not a difficulty in converting floats to ints but rather a problem with missing data. Some values simply aren't there, so does it make sense to drop them, or would you prefer they be the value 0, or some other value? It all depends on the context, does it make sense for missing data to be 0? Is that a safe and valid assumption of your data?

Comment: Problem is, if i had the opportunity id drop the columns. But Im working on a masters programming course and i have to follow strict rules. It is not mentioned where I can or cannot so I am working on the lines as if I cannot do so. Out of the 4 columns of interest, 1 has no missing entries, and the others equally have 55 missing data entries out of 18,500.

Comment: If you describe your thought process and justification for doing things, I am sure your professor will be understanding. Real life data is never perfect so following strict processes is not realistic. Do what you feel makes sense in the context of the data and the problem you are solving. Best of luck!